# Custom UI5 control does not update bound value

Tags: data-binding, sapui5, sap-fiori

How can I pass OData value to property of a custom UI5 control? I tried this but it's **not working**.
If I try passing it to normal control like `<Text>`, it's **working** fine.
If I try passing a static value, it's **working** fine too:

```xml
<cc:CheckPrice valuePrice="{Price}"/> <!--❌-->
<Text text="{Price}"/> <!--✔️-->
<cc:CheckPrice valuePrice="1000"/> <!--✔️-->
```

How can I pass the value from a remote OData service to show it like in Text control?

[image: Screenshot of the rendered custom control]

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/Control",
    "sap/m/Label",
    "sap/m/Button"
], function (Control, Label, Button) {
    "use strict";

    return Control.extend("zgutfiory.zguttestfiorylr.controls.CheckPrice", {
        metadata: {
            properties: {
                "valuePrice": {
                    type: "string",
                    bindable: "bindable"
                }
            },
            aggregations: {
                "_label": {
                    type: "sap.m.Label",
                    multiple: false,
                    visibility: "hidden"
                },
                "_button": {
                    type: "sap.m.Button",
                    multiple: false,
                    visibility: "hidden"
                }
            },
            events: {
                // ...
            }
        },

        init: function () {
            this.setAggregation("_label", new Label({
                text: "{i18n>controlCheckPrice}"
            }).addStyleClass("sapUiSmallMargin"));
            this.setAggregation("_button", new Button({
                text: "{i18n>controlCheckPrice}",
                press: [this._onSubmit, this]
            }).addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMarginTopBottom"));
        },

        _onSubmit: function (oEvent) {
            // ...
        },

        renderer: function (oRm, oControl) {
            oRm.write('<div class="zgutCheckPriceWrap">');
            oRm.write('<div class="zgutPriceWrap">' + oControl.getValuePrice() + '</div>');
            oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_label"));
            oRm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation("_button"));
            oRm.write('</div>');
        }
    });
});
```

UI5 version: 1.92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed adding some mandatory control data in the render function. When the model value changes (e.g. `ODataModel` receiving data), the control with the bound property needs to be identifiable by an `id` at least so that the control can be updated. In your case, the `id` was not rendered.

To add the required control data, use:

- `oRm.openStart("div", oCotrol)` in case of the new *semantic rendering* (UI5 ≥ 1.67).
- `oRm.writeControlData(oControl)` in case of the now-deprecated *string-based rendering* (UI5 ≤ 1.66). **Note:** please use `.writeEscaped` for `oControl.getValuePrice()` here to avoid XSS.

Also, make sure to call the super function if you overwrite borrowed methods (e.g. `init`). This is especially important for lifecycle hooks.

Sample: https://embed.plnkr.co/gnmPoh3KS7L3DDXZ?show=controls%2FCheckPrice.js,preview

---

See the **[API reference: `sap/ui/core/RenderManager`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.RenderManager)** for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The binding for custom control is exactly same as standard control. Below points have to be considered:

- If the parent container e.g. view is bound with a context, you have to provide the relative path of the attribute you are binding the value with e.g. `{Price}`. Otherwise, give absolute path e.g. `{/Price}`
- If the model is named, make sure to provide the name when binding. E.g. `{namedModel>/Price}`
- Path can be multi-level as well. E.g. `{ToCategory/CategoryName}` for OData property binding using NavigationProperty `ToCategory`

Comment: Thanks, but its not working - maybe i do something wrong in control? With Text control its working, with my control its not:     <Text text="{Price}"/>
    <cc:checkPrice id="checkPrice" valuePrice="{Price}" class="sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd" />

Answer (score -1):

Seems likely that you are maybe just missing the leading slash?

`<cc:checkPrice id="checkPrice" valuePrice="{/Price}" class="sapUiSmallMarginBeginEnd" />`

Comment: No, with leading slash not working too. <Text text="{Price}"/> - working, but my control doesnt work.